# How can I mock a method that returns a Task<IList<>>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, task, moq

I am trying to unit test a method that returns a Task>:

```
void Main()
{
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository>();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } });  // works

    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } }));  // error

    var result = mockRepo.Object.GetAll();
    result.Dump();
}

public interface IRepository
{
    Task<IList<MyModel>> GetAllAsync();
    IList<MyModel> GetAll();
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But the Task returning method generates a compiler error:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.MyModel>'
>   to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList<UserQuery.MyModel>'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use ReturnsAync method:

```
IList<MyModel> expected = new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" }};
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(expected);
```

Comment: Thanks, did just find it,

Answer (score 3):

Posted to soon, found out that Moq has the ReturnsAsync method.

```
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync()).ReturnsAsync((new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } });
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your list to IList:

```
Task.FromResult((IList<MyModel>) new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } })
```

Or define the generic param:

```
Task.FromResult<IList<MyModel>>(new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } })
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works. But I found a more elegant solution using the ReturnsAsync method.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the result to `IList`

```
Task.FromResult((IList)new List() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is that your method should be returning `Task<IList>` and You are returning `Task<List>` you can't do that - they are of different types and they do not support contravariance or covariance. You need to cast your return type

```
 mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult((IList<MyModel>)new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } }));
```

Comment: Nope, your conclusion is wrong. Read my question again.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not, since my answer is exactly the same as everybody else's, and it obviously works - and the reason is the generics covariance and contravariance. Anyways, the accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: No, your statement: "Well your problem is that your method should be returning Task<IList> and You are returning Task<List> you can't do that" is false. That's what I am objecting against. It is in fact returning a Task of IList, as stated in the question.

Comment: Task.FromResult(new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel { Name = "Test" } })

This Piece of code, inside your .Returns() results in a return value of Task<List> not Task<IList>